# Override Output Caching duration for Client caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, wcf-rest

I have a REST based WCF service which returns JSON data as response. To improve performance Output Caching is enabled with location as **ANY** and duration **1 hr**. 
I want to allow clients to cache the response for a period of **1 month** while keeping the data cached on the server for only 1 hr, to do this i added the following lines in my code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

but this value is overridden by the Output Caching profile value. How can i override the value set by the Output Caching profile

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but it may help you: as [anir](http://forums.iis.net/members/anilr.aspx) writes [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1159142/1910555.aspx#1910555):

> The headers for the HttpCachePolicy are added by asp.net after the caching module runs and so are not part of the response that is cached.  If you want the headers to be cached, just use HttpResponse.SetHeader/AddHeader etc in your code.